# Lua sorting. Strange order after sort

Tags: sorting, lua

```
crdsClear={{y=56,x=50,symbolName=3,},
{y=56,x=29,symbolName=2,},
{y=56,x=99,symbolName=2,},
{y=56,x=9,symbolName=5,},
{y=56,x=69,symbolName=5,},
{y=56,x=19,symbolName=4,},
{y=56,x=59,symbolName=4,},
{y=56,x=89,symbolName=4,},
{y=56,x=40,symbolName=7,},
{y=56,x=80,symbolName=6,},}



tmp2={}
ywf = 1
table.sort(crdsClear,
    function(a,b)
        tmp2[ywf]=""
        for i=1, #crdsClear, 1 do tmp2[ywf] = tmp2[ywf].."\t"..crdsClear[i].x     end
        ywf = ywf + 1
        if  a.x <= b.x then print(a.x.." <= "..b.x.." true") else print(a.x.." <= "..b.x.." false") end
        return a.x <= b.x --  a.y <= b.y and
    end
)

-- Create string
order=""
print(#crdsClear)
result = {[1]=""}
for i=1, #crdsClear, 1 do
    order = order..crdsClear[i].x.." "
    result[1] = result[1].. crdsClear[i].symbolName
end
print(order)
print(result[1])
```

I have .x order after sorting:
9 19 59 29 40 50 69 80 89 99
and string:
5442735642
Why i have incorrect order?
If i change:
    return a.x <= b.x
to:
    return a.x < b.x
then order full correctly.

Answer (score 4):

From the Lua reference manual:

> If comp is given, then it must be a function that receives two list
>   elements and returns true when the first element must come before the
>   second in the final order (so that, after the sort, i < j implies not
>   comp(list[j],list[i])).

Using `<=` here results in an invalid sort function which in some cases will invoke an error message and/or an incomplete sort result.

Use `return a.x < b.x` instead.

Comment: what's the difference how do I get true or false? Sort function cant know how i compare values.

Comment: @DarkMaster yes the function cannot know how you compare values. but it requires you to compare values in a way that does not cause problems while sorting. try to print the value pairs in your comparison function and see what happens right befor the sort ends.

Comment: i did it before create topic and i taked shock... It compare elements 3 and 7, after compare it swap 7 and 5. How? Idk....

Comment: return not (a.x > b.x) have some problems.

Comment: @DarkMaster of course. what did you expect? it's the same as `a.x <= b` hence you get the same problems...